# Kineticjs: shadow blur is not working after applying filters

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am working on HTML5 canvas. I am using KineticJS in my project. I need to add shadow to the image when user clicks on it. I am doing this

```
image.setShadowBlur(50);
image.attrs.shadowOpacity = 5;
```

It's working fine. But the problem is that once I apply filters on the image after that it does not work. To apply filters I am doing this

```
image.cache();
image.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale]);
```

I don't know why the shadow blur is not working. Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GzpbCQ4XjCF7lSg4pSZ3?p=preview). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recache image after applying shadow.

```
image.setShadowBlur(50);
image.clearCache();
image.cache();
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/93MPz7MWuInJti7IPucu?p=preview)

Also it is better to use [Konva](http://konvajs.github.io/). It has a lot of fixes in caching function.

Comment: You nailed it... Thanks a ton. I am planning to switch to Konva. It also has a very helpful doc.